# Why move_upload_file not work for apk file?

Tags: php, file-upload

i have code like here.

```
$upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'docx', 'apk', ); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            // $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
            $userpic = $imgFile;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size '50MB'
                if($imgSize < 50000000)             {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF, APK, DOC files are allowed.";      
            }
```

I want to upload apk file from my form upload, the file succeed moved to the specific directory but it not working if i upload apk file.
I have no idea why it can't, i already add apk extention in $valid_extension array.
How i can fix it?

Comment: you got just a few conditions in your code and you still cannot debug it yourself or event `print_r()` vars to see?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

Second parameter need an absolute path to file with file name

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$absolutepathtofile.extension);
```